# problemas com o mysql connector no python

Tags: mysql, python

Estou com problemas para conectar no mysql.connector..
No php myadmin, conecta normal, e tambem no bash está entrando normal no mysql.. So no python dá esse problema..

```
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='disc',user='root',password='12345678', use_unicode=True, charset='utf8')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
self.connect(**kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
self._open_connection()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
self._socket.open_connection()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 512, in open_connection
errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
```

Alguem sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: qual a versão do seu python?

Comment: versao 2.7 ....

Comment: considere usar a última versão do python uma vez que o python2.7 não terá mais suporte no final desse ano

Comment: eu ja tentei readaptar meus codigos pra python3 mas encontrei muitos problemas : ( vou usar o python2.7 enquanto der

Comment: detalhe mais sobre a implementação que você usou e também o erro

Comment: Olha, pelo que analisei ate agora o problema parece esta no mysql, por algum motivo ele nao quer se conectar via tcp

Comment: Me disseram que pode ser que o phpmyadmin se conecte via socket, e o python se conecta via tcp, e por isso nao esta conectando

Comment: Consegui resolver, bastou descomentar a linha no script de serviço do mysql, a linha SKIP="--skip-networking" ela vem habilitada por padrao no slackware : ( nao sabia disso

Comment: Muito bom, marque sua resposta como resolvida pra finalizar a sua pergunta ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido, era problema no serviço do slackware, que vem por default a linha
SKIP="--skip-networking" bastou descomentar ela que funcionou